# Add new value combination to unique values, many fields symbology in Arc

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, symbology

We have a zoning layer symbolized with unique values, many fields. We use three layers and get a combination of 50 - 60 symbols, at a guess. How can I add a new symbol for a new combination of values in the three fields without undoing all the existing symbology and starting from scratch. Thanks.

ArcGIS 10.0 sp1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to click the 'add values...' button and click the complete list option to see all available combinations, or use the add button to create a new item that isn't currently present in the dataset. adding one new item should not change the existing symbology

Comment: Thanks. I'd swear I tried that several times, no luck. But now it works. Go figure.